# FFMPG Concat two video quality issue

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm trying to concat two mp4 video files using ffmpg (with the below command), a main video and a secondary one, the main video always have 1080x1920 resolution and the resulting video should have the some resolution.

val concat = "-i ${mainVideoPath} -i ${secondVideoPath} -filter_complex [0:v]scale=1080:1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,setsar=1:1,pad=1080:1920:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[s0];[1:v]scale=1080:1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,setsar=1:1,pad=1080:1920:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[s1];[s0][s1]concat=n=2:v=1[v] -map [v] $resultVideoPath"

The concat work fine but the main part of my resulting video always lose quality although the resulting video has the same resolution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're telling scale to fit the main video inside a 1080x1920 canvas, so it will resize it to 1080x607, which is a loss of resolution.

Comment: @Gyan why it resize the video since the canvas is 1080x1920 and the video resolution is 1080x1920 also ? I don't get it

Comment: You mention that "*main video always have 1920x1080*"

Comment: that's my bad it's 1080x1920 :s i edited the question